# AttributeError: module 'vlc' has no attribute 'Instance'

Tags: python, vlc

Im trying to record a livestream using vlc. 
I guess, the problem is that my app cant detect installed vlc. I installed it using

```
pip install python-vlc
```

Ive tried to put my .py file into vlc folder, but then i get another issue

```
[00212d24] main libvlc error: No modules were found, refusing to start. Check that you properly gave a module path with --plugin-path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asdads.py", line 25, in <module>
    grabar_audio(radio, datos)
  File "asdads.py", line 13, in grabar_audio
    player = instancia.media_player_new()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'
```

```
import sys
import vlc
from time import sleep

def grabar_audio(stream, parametros):

    radio = stream
    datos = parametros
    instancia = vlc.Instance()

    player = instancia.media_player_new()
    media = instancia.media_new(radio, datos)
    media.get_mrl()
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: That error message at the top looks important.  Perhaps you should address that first.

Comment: place a copy of `vlc.py` in the same directory as your asdads.py file

Answer (score 0):

python-vlc is a binding of python to vlc program (or wrapper libraries). It is a way to run vlc program via python (python -> binding -> vlc). So you need to do the following steps:

```
1)  copy vlc.py to where you run your application
2)  download vlc program and install it in your machine
3)  restart your machine and run notebook again
```

You have done step #1 so you may download and install vlc (64-bit) in this link: https://download.cnet.com/VLC-Media-Player-64-bit/3000-13632_4-75761094.html